# Complex symbology across multiple fields ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I would like to symbolize my layer with a color A for features with only 'Yes' value in one of the field X or in the field Y and with a color B features with both a 'Yes' value in field X and in field Y.

Feature | Field X |Field Y
01      | Yes     | NULL
02      |Yes      |Yes

In this simple example feature 01 should be as color A and feature 02 with color B.

Is this possible with ArcGIS symbology?

Comment: are you asking how to use unique value with two field ? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/unique-value.htm

Comment: I do think that the answer is yes. I further do some readings, and think I need some arcade code to make 2 groups: one when 2 fields or more and not NULL and one for features with only 1 notNULL field. Still looking for the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working answer for ArcGis Community (@JohannesLindner)
This workflow is working to symbolize values with 2 or more field non empty on one hand and values with less than 2 non empty fields on the other hand.

```
// get an array of the $feature's values
    var values = [$feature.FieldX, $feature.FieldY, $feature.FieldZ]
    // get the count of non-empty values
    var c = 0
    for(var i in values) {
        c += !IsEmpty(values[i])
    }
    // return true if 2 or more values are non-empty
    return c >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use unique value with two field you will get all possible combination of value from field X and Y.

Then select the combination with only 'Yes' value in one of the field X or in the field Y (hold the control key to select several combination) and right click (on the value field, not the symbol one) and choose group value you may now set the color A

For the color B you may use the same procedure (group symbol classes and give the resulting classe color B)